# .NET Dir$ Function on Network Path

Tags: vb.net

I have a network path that contains hundred of thousands .wav files.  When I do the following:

```
FileBuffer = Dir$("\\MEDIASERVER\*.wav", FileAttribute.Archive)
```

The line freezes forever. I have literally let it run a day, and it never returns with execution.  I then decided to test the symptom with a dir command in DOS.  Same symptom.

I then wondered if I would get the same symptom if I added a prefix to the search pattern narrowing my results.  I did this in DOS:

```
DIR 0009*.wav
```

Worked like a charm.  So, armed with this knowledge, I went back to my VB.NET project and applied a similar solution:

```
FileBuffer = Dir$("\\MEDIASERVER\0009*.wav", FileAttribute.Archive)
```

Doesn't get stuck, actually does the search.  But I was surprised by the first result:

FileBuffer came back with the following value:

```
003925034541228334146804222014065036AM005020MIF.wav
```

This does not match the pattern I asked for.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?  Is there a known bug with DIR$?  Is there a way to achieve what I want without enumerating 100% of the files in the network share?

Additional Information if it's relevant:
Developement Machine: Windows 7 Pro, VS 2013 Pro
Network Server: Linux Centos 5.0 (I have the same issue with a network drive running Windows 7 Pro).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are they hidden files?

Comment: Does `DIR \\MEDIASERVER\0009*.wav` work in DOS?

Comment: The command works in DOS.  I am actually getting the same feedback in DOS as I am in my .NET Project though.  They are normal files.  Nothing special about them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry for just posting the question, and already getting the answer.  The question about whether or not it worked properly in DOS helped narrow my troubleshooting.  I came across a couple of pages on the net stating that DIR will come back with unexpected results.  They state that it's because of the 8.3 naming convention.  I then decided to see if there was any other constraints I could add to my program.  I changed the pattern to:

```
DIR \\MEDIASERVER\0009*MIF.wav
```

And now I am getting the expected results.  This cannot be because of the 8.3 Naming convention though.  It's something else, but at least I got this working.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: why use dir? use a `For Each` loop, with `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` classes.